# How to use Cucumber/Factory Girl with Persistent Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, factory-bot

I use `db/seeds.rb` to populate my database with 2 user roles ("Admin", "User") that will never change.  When i run tests though, the seed data does not get carried over and the results are error tests.

When i try to run cucumber i get the following error:

> Using the default profile... Feature: Sign in   In order to get access
>   to protected sections of the site   A valid user   Should be able to
>   sign in
>
> > Scenario: User is not signed up                       #
> >     features/users/sign_in.feature:6   Not registered: role
> >     (ArgumentError)
> >     /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.rc4/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:15:in
> >     `find'
> >
> >     /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.rc4/lib/factory_girl.rb:39:in`
> >     factory_by_name'
> >     /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.rc4/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb:53:in
> >     `default_strategy'
> >
> >     /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/factory_girl-2.0.0.rc4/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb:146:in`
> >     Factory'
> >     /Users/x/rails/ply_rails/features/support/db_setup.rb:6:in
> >     `Before'
> >         Given I am not logged in                            #
> >     features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:36

Here is what my setup looks like:

```
# features/support/db_setup.rb
Before do
  # Truncates the DB before each Scenario,
  # make sure you've added database_cleaner to your Gemfile.
  DatabaseCleaner.clean

  Factory(:role, :name => 'Admin')
  Factory(:role, :name => 'User')
end



# features/users/sign_in.feature
Feature: Sign in
  In order to get access to protected sections of the site
  A valid user
  Should be able to sign in

    Scenario: User is not signed up  # THIS IS LINE 6
      Given I am not logged in
      And no user exists with an email of "user@user.com"
      When I go to the sign in page
      And I sign in as "user@user.com/password"
      Then I should see "Invalid email or password."
      And I go to the home page
      And I should be signed out



# features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb
Given /^I am a "([^"]*)" named "([^"]*)" with an email "([^"]*)" and password "([^"]*)"$/ do |role, name, email, password|
  User.new(:name => name,
            :email => email,
            :role => Role.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize),
            :password => password,
            :password_confirmation => password).save!
end
```

Not sure where to start on getting this working, thank you for your help/time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the point of tests is to start with a clean database, i.e a consistent state, so it's kind of good that everything gets wiped.

Secondly, in terms of cucumber, you should be defining a Background block to do the set up. This will run for each scenario, and has the benefit of every action being explicitly known. This is especially useful if you use the cucumber scenario plain text to show to clients. So you should do something like:

```
Background:
    Given that the role "Admin" exists
    And that the role "User" exists

Scenario:
    etc
```

And make custom steps for the `that the role [blank] exists` that will create the role for you.

Comment: i had thought of doing this but then assumed that because most of my App's activities take place within the context of a logged in user i'd ultimately end up duplicating that `Background` clause in almost every controller i test.  Thinking about it now, I think this is actually OK since it makes the tests more readable and obvious, but i was just wondering what your (or anyone's) thoughts are on this.  Thanks!!

Comment: I myself love DRY programming, but when it comes to tests, I don't like to take too many chances, and being verbose and explicit can be okay (again: just my opinion). I see nothing wrong with repeating some steps in a Background over multiple cucumber features. If you want too, you can be a bit less verbose and make a step like `Given that reference data exists` and make all your data there. I like in cucumber tests when things are spelled out nicely, because integration/acceptance tests are more complex.

Comment: Thank you!  That's how i've done it now and it's working great.